# Why is the query getting slow after few executions?

Tags: postgresql

As part of my code I'm using postgres and doing the following:
(starting from a clean table)

1. Adding a lot of records to a table (around 1M)
2. Performing analyze on the table
3. Executing the query described below.

The query:

```
DELETE FROM relation
WHERE
relation.id = ANY(
  SELECT relation.id
  from relation
  INNER JOIN pending_relation_removal ON
  (relation.from_id = pending_relation_removal.from_id or relation.to_id = pending_relation_removal.to_id)
  AND relation.data->>'source' = pending_relation_removal.source
  AND (pending_relation_removal.types is null or relation.data->>'type' = ANY(pending_relation_removal.types))
)
AND NOT EXISTS (
  select 1
  from updated_relations
  where updated_relations.id = relation.id
);
```

The explain plan is something like:

```
Delete on relation  (cost=233487.70..5013152.23 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=11662778.319..11662778.334 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  ->  Merge Join  (cost=233487.70..5013152.23 rows=17346 width=18) (actual time=1569.402..11661171.171 rows=123213 loops=1)"
"        Merge Cond: (((relation.data ->> 'source'::text)) = pending_relation_removal.source)"
"        Join Filter: (((relation.from_id = pending_relation_removal.from_id) OR (relation.to_id = pending_relation_removal.to_id)) AND ((pending_relation_removal.types IS NULL) OR ((relation.data ->> 'type'::text) = ANY (pending_relation_removal.types))))"
"        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 25481733219"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=108294.39..108400.75 rows=42544 width=177) (actual time=1221.499..1398.983 rows=42544 loops=1)"
"              Sort Key: ((relation.data ->> 'source'::text))"
"              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 8416kB"
"              ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=0.85..101239.96 rows=42544 width=177) (actual time=0.069..1177.150 rows=42544 loops=1)"
"                    Merge Cond: (relation.id = updated_edges.id)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using relation_pkey on relation  (cost=0.42..49714.15 rows=882507 width=179) (actual time=0.056..462.980 rows=882507 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using updated_relations_pkey on updated_relations  (cost=0.42..38820.01 rows=839963 width=14) (actual time=0.008..563.235 rows=839963 loops=1)"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=125193.31..128188.07 rows=598953 width=86) (actual time=329.863..4869749.000 rows=25481813889 loops=1)"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=125193.31..126690.69 rows=598953 width=86) (actual time=329.855..458.086 rows=598953 loops=1)"
"                    Sort Key: pending_relation_removal.source"
"                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 26376kB"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on pending_relation_removal  (cost=0.00..10394.53 rows=598953 width=86) (actual time=0.067..105.701 rows=598953 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 2.318 ms"
"Execution Time: 11662792.828 ms"
```

In most of the cases, it works great and the query is performed very fast (around 20ms). However, from a certain point the execution becomes very slow (few hours).
When examining the explain plan we see that it became slow since it stopped using the index and started to review the entire table.

We're now considering collecting more statistics and forcing the query to use the index.

Any suggestion that will assist us ensure that the query will continue to run fast?

Comment: What is the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the slow query?

Comment: Your selecting from a table you are deleting from. Dead rows hang around. Likely you will need a vacuum/analyse to update the stats mark the dead rows as re-usable . You may even remove some empty pages. If not, try a repack, or vacuum full.

Comment: we're doing analyse today but from some point it doesn't help. We'll try the repack/vacuum full.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - I've edited the query with the explain I have.

Comment: Also, please show the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for when it is not slow, for comparison.

Comment: What do you mean "from a certain point"?  If you always start from a clean table and run one query with no LIMIT, then how can all points not be identical to each other?

Comment: I think for a better performance you have to pass throw temp tables: first get all filtered data in new temp table then execute the delete query based on the temp table created previously

Comment: @jjanes - not sure why, but as far as we see it doesn't act the same between the different executions.

Comment: @El.MENSI - so just to make sure I understand- we'll take the inner select into a temp table and then get the ids from there in order to delete? Did I get it correctly?

Comment: That's what I thought about, I think you won't have performance issues with select joins and not exist clauses at first place. Then you can delete whatever you want.